# Is the doc wrong about interpreting \xhh

Tags: tcl, language-lawyer

This is from the main TCL doc:

```
\xhh   The hexadecimal digits hh give an eight-bit hexadecimal value for the 
Unicode character that will be inserted. Any number of hexadecimal digits may be 
present; however, **all but the last two are ignored** (the result is always a 
one-byte quantity).
```

My doubt is this part, `all but the last two are ignored`. Here is my experiment:

```
>set a "\x22"
"
>set a "\x2230"
"30
```

So you can see that it is the first 2 hexadecimal digits are taken and the rest are just treated as plain char.

Do I miss something?

[EDIT] Looks like I am right, here is from parser.c of tcl8.6:

```
 860     case 'x':
 861         count += TclParseHex(p+1, (numBytes > 3) ? 2 : numBytes-2, &result);
```

So only the first immediate 2 digits are taken. Weird, how come nobody finds this doc error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a place where the behaviour changed from Tcl 8.5 (and before) to 8.6. It was a bug fix because the old behaviour was so damn weird that nobody ever expected it. (Or the Spanish Inquisition, but I digress…)

In 8.6, [the documentation says](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M27):

> **\x***hh*
>   The hexadecimal digits *hh* (one or two of them) give an eight-bit hexadecimal value for the Unicode character that will be inserted. The upper bits of the Unicode character will be 0.

In 8.5, [the documentation says](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M27):

> **\x***hh*
>   The hexadecimal digits *hh* give an eight-bit hexadecimal value for the Unicode character that will be inserted. Any number of hexadecimal digits may be present; however, all but the last two are ignored (the result is always a one-byte quantity). The upper bits of the Unicode character will be 0.

The difference is plain, and 8.5 and 8.6 behave differently here. The change was due to [TIP #388](http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/388.html) *“Extending Unicode literals past the BMP”* (part of a general programme of fixes, some of which had to be postponed to after 8.6 due to the impact on the ABI) which was voted on in September 2011; project lead was Jan Nijtmans.
I remember voting for that TIP, and that fix was something I was very glad was in there.

Sorry it wasn't flagged as a Potential Incompatibility. Missed that one (probably because the old behaviour was so badly broken that nobody really believed that we hadn't fixed it long before…)